# Deriving Concentration of Measure Given Conditional Concentration

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

I have a question regarding a couple of concentrated random variables. I have tried abstracting the original setting in order to ask the question here, reducing the details to what I believe is all that should be necessary.

Consider a filtration $\mathcal{F}_0 \subset \mathcal{F}_1 \subset \dots$ (where $\mathcal{F}_0$ is the trivial $\sigma$-field), a sequence of (subgaussian or subexponential) random variables $(X_i)_{i \geq 0}$, a sequence $(Y_i)_{i \geq 0}$ such that $Y_i = \mathbb{E}[X_i | \mathcal{F}_{i-2}]$ for every $i \geq 2$, and $\varepsilon \in (0, 1]$ such that the following holds:
\begin{align}
(i) \quad \mathbb{P}(|X_{i+1} - Y_{i+1}| \geq \varepsilon | \mathcal{F}_{i-1}) &\leq \exp{\left(-C \min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{X_i}, \frac{\varepsilon^2}{X_i^2}\right\}\right)} \\
(ii) \quad \mathbb{P}(X_i \geq \varepsilon) &\leq \exp{(-\tilde{C} \varepsilon^2)}
\end{align}
for $i \geq 0$. Then, combine these facts to show
$$ \mathbb{P}(|X_{i+1} - Y_{i+1}| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \exp{(-\bar{C} \varepsilon^2)}, $$
where $C, \tilde{C}, \bar{C}$ are nonzero constants.

I think this may somehow work inductively, although I cannot explain why you can apparently disregard the conditioning... Is there a way to relate the second condition with the first to somehow get rid of the conditioning? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: I did realize that by substituting, one gets (for small $\varepsilon$)
$$ \mathbb{P}(|X_{i+1} - Y_{i+1}| \geq \varepsilon X_i | \mathcal{F_{i-1}}) \leq \exp{(-C\varepsilon^2)}. $$

Additionally, using Mr.Gandalf Sauron's hint below, one can get rid of the conditioning by taking expectation, and using the monotonicity of the expectation one gets
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(|X_{i+1} - Y_{i+1}| \geq \varepsilon) &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(\dots|\mathcal{F}_{i-1})] \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[\exp{(-C \min\{\frac{\varepsilon}{X_i}, \frac{\varepsilon^2}{X_i^2}\})}] \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(\exp{(-C \min \{\frac{\varepsilon}{X_i}, \frac{\varepsilon^2}{X_i^2}\})} \geq t) dt
\end{align}
Now, if I could say that $1/X$ is again subgaussian and the squared term in the minimum is the smaller one, then this would follow from the properties of the MGF of subgaussian r.v.'s. Can I say this though? I don't think it is clear that the inverse is again subgaussian, is it...?

---

Edit 2: I realized the $Y_i$'s should not be deterministic, but are conditional expectations themselves. Changed above.

Comment: Subgaussian generally means that $P(|X|>\epsilon)\leq \exp(-C\epsilon^{2})$ for all $\epsilon>0$ for some fixed positive constant $C$. That being said, one can get rid of the conditioning by just taking expectation. $E(|X_{i}|^{p})$ can be expressed as $\int_{0}^{\infty}pt^{p-1}P(|X_{i}|\geq t)\,dt$. Although, I don't see how this would relate to $E(\exp(-\frac{C}{X_{i}})$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks for the hint, but I don't quite understand what you mean by getting rid of conditioning by taking expectation... What am I taking the expectation of here? I am not familiar with this strategy...

Comment: $P(|X_{i}-Y_{i}>\epsilon|\mathcal{F}_{i})=E(\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_{i}-Y_{i}>\epsilon|\}}|\mathcal{F}_{i})$.  So $E(E(\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_{i}-Y_{i}>\epsilon|\}}|\mathcal{F}_{i})=E(\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_{i}-Y_{i}>\epsilon|\}})=P(|X_{i}-Y_{i}|>\epsilon)$

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you

Comment: In partiuclar, for any $\mathcal{F}$ measurable $X$, you have $E(E(X|\mathcal{G})=E(X)$ for a subsigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ by very definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this property. My mind just went blank and I didn't think of it :D

Comment: Also, you are conditioning on $\mathcal{F_{i-1}}$ and you have $X_{i}$ on RHS which are not necessarily $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$ measurable.